# ASP.NET Web API - how can I have one controller that will match ANY route?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, routes

I want to create a controller that looks like this:

```
public class GenericController : ApiController
{
    public string Get() {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

And I want to invoke this method from any of these URL requests (assuming `http://domain/` is the domain):

`GET http://domain/`

`GET http://domain/billy`

`GET http://domain/susie?whatever=true`

(I feel like this should be simple, but I'm unable to accomplish it with any combination of controller and WebApiConfig code.)

Answer (score 0):

You can set your API route to something like this:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
       name: "API Default",
       template: "{name?}", new { controller = "Api"  });
```

and then in your controller:

```
[Route("{name?}")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ApiController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public string Get(string name)
        {
            // do something with name 
            return name;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In `WebApiConfig.Register()`:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "{*url}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Generic" }
);
```